# Opacidade de imagem linkada pelo CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Existe alguma possibilidade de dar atributos para um item linkado via CSS?

```css
#content-homepage {
    background-image: url(../img/back.jpg);
}
```

Queria diminuir a opacidade dessa imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opcao 1: `opacity` funciona em todos veja em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Browser_compatibility

```css
div.exemplo{
      width:150px;
      height:150px;
      background: url('https://i.imgur.com/r3MHkRT.jpg');
      opacity: 0.5
    }
```

```html
<div class="exemplo"></div>
```

Opcao 2: `filter` veja as
compatibilidades: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility_2

```css
div.exemplo{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/r3MHkRT.jpg');
  filter: opacity(50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="exemplo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja este exemplo:

```css
div.teste {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

div.teste::after {
  content: "";
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/hlwO5D2.png');
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: -1; */
}
```

```html
<div class="teste">
</div>
```

Basta aplicar no seu projeto e voalá!

Caso o fundo esteja sobrepondo algum elemento do seu projeto, basta descomentar a linha do *z-index* conforme seus elementos.

> Fonte: [CSS Tricks - Transparent Background Images](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)
>
> Imagem: [PSDgraphics - Abstract Purple Background](http://www.psdgraphics.com/backgrounds/abstract-purple-background/)

Comment: Tentei fazer em meu código e a imagem sumiu

Comment: Tentou habilitar e definir o z-index? Apresentou algum erro no console?

Comment: Tentei, nenhum erro

Comment: O problema é que a imagem está linkada via CSS, dar atributos pra um atributo parece impossível ;(